# Pandas Combine Dataframe Options for More than one instance of Key?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataframe

I am using Python 3.4, and Windows 7. Here is a sample of my first Dataframe: [Sample Data](https://gist.github.com/ahlusar1989/42708e6a3ca0aed9b79b)

Here is my second DataFrame: [Sample Data 2](https://gist.github.com/ahlusar1989/26eb4ce1578e0844eb82)

My goal is use the "RTID" as my key. However, as evidenced by the data that I have parsed from another data structure, there appears to be duplicate keys. Moreover, the requirement necessitates that each RTID has a unique transaction type.

I have many more of these data frames (some of which also share common column header names) that need to be combined into one cohesive dataframe. Each row value's integrity is maintained with its header. Duplicate column names should only appear once in the final product with the respective values appended sequentially with each the respective row (hence my initial thought for using the RTID column as a key) and for missing or non-applicable values  - an empty space. My initial thought was to concatenate, but, due to the various dtypes, I receive the following error:

```
AssertionError: invalid dtype determination in get_concat_dtype
```

This can be sourced here: [Pandas/Internals.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals.py)

[@EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) and [@BrianPendleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4080476/brian-pendleton) were very helpful with the Memory management issue.

I am wondering if join and merge could be valid use cases for this specific context. I welcome feedback on this.

Comment: You definitely want to do an outer join on both frames?

Comment: Don't merge on any columns with null values, you will get an inexact match which will grow your merged df exponentially, I'd either drop them or assign some dummy value

Comment: @BrianPendleton Thanks for bringing that to the fore. From what I understand I think the requirement is to have   the union of all of the tables - not solely the intersection from the shared "keys" (in this case the headers). I think that I am over thinking the problem as the source dataframe yields 6 "child" dataframes that have - in some instances these datframes have the same header. Hence, the rationale for this. I am also editing the OP to provide more clarity on the data and the composition of the headers. This will be reflected in the Gist that I originally shared.

Comment: @EdChum Understood - thanks for the pointer. I will try to receive clarification on if that is tenable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am referencing **pg. 188** of [Python for Data Analysis](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023784.do) for my answer. After reviewing the various methods offered, I was able to achieve the end product.

Citing the above two sample data sources (and dropping the indexes):

```
sample1 = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv', dtype=str, error_bad_lines = False)
sample2 = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv', dtype=str, error_bad_lines = False)
sample_concat = pd.concat([sample1, sample2], keys = ['one', 'two'], ignore_index=True)
```

This produced the correct ouput. It turns out that I was overthinking the problem. In this context, the row index is not meaningful. The `ignore_index = False` parameter allows one to not preserve indexes along the concatenation axis. This is useful as I was not seeking to find the intersection of the data sets (which, in theory should not be apparent in the data structure that I am wrangling).